# Augmented reality (AR) into the three.js editor shows an empty scene

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, augmented-reality

I am running the [Three.JS open-source web editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) (the [source code is here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/editor)) for my project, and modified it so it works as a standalone. I have configured the editor to satisfy my needs but now I wish to implement augmented reality. For that I'm adding an [`ARButton`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/webxr/ARButton.js) using the following code:

```js
window.editor.renderer.xr.enabled = true;
const arButton = ARButton.createButton(window.editor.renderer);
document.body.appendChild(arButton);
```

Where `window.editor.renderer` is the project renderer. The problem is that when I click `START AR`, I'm sent on an empty AR playground even though I **have** added objects.

So I thought: maybe I'm not using the right renderer instance?

WebGLRenderer instances are created multiple times across the editor source code, but by testing each of them I believe the only one which truly matters is the instance created in [`Sidebar.Project.Renderer.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/editor/js/Sidebar.Project.Renderer.js#L111). I added, at the bottom of the `createRenderer` function, this line:

```js
window.editor.renderer = currentRenderer;
```

Again, however, when I click `START AR` an empty scene pops-up. I also tried it on my phone (I usually use the WebXR API Emulator by Mozilla) and it's the same.

##### I don't understand and on top of that I can't find a minimal reproductible example. Every small test I do *outside* of the Three.JS editor works flawlessly.

Some screenshots: [image: screenshot of the editor scene]
[image: screenshot of the scene, empty]